# how to extract the key from the log in python

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

i write the python code ,in order to extract key from the log.And using the same log,it worked well in one machine.But when i run it in hadoop,it failed.I guess there are some bugs when using `regex`.Who can give me some comments?Is `regex` can't support hadoop?

This python code is aim to extract `qry` and `rc` ,and count the value of `rc` ,and then print it as `qry  query_count rc_count` .When run it in hadoop,it report

`java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1`.

I search google,there may some bug in your mapper code.So how can i fix it?

log formats like that,

> > NOTICE: 01-03 23:57:23:  [a.cpp][b][222] show_ver=11 sid=ae1d esid=6WVj uid=D1 a=20  qry=cars qid0=293 loc_src=4 phn=0  mid=0 wvar=c op=0 qry_src=0 op_type=1 src=110|120|111 at=60942 rc=3|1|1 discount=20 indv_type=0 rep_query=

And my python code is that

```
import sys
import re

for line in sys.stdin:
    count_result = 0
    line = line.strip()
    match=re.search('.*qry=(.*?)qid0.*rc=(.*?)discount',line).groups()
    if (len(match)<2):
       continue
    counts_tmp = match[1].strip()
    counts=counts_tmp.split('|')
    for count in counts:
       if count.isdigit():
         count_result += int(count)
    key_tmp = match[0].strip()
    if key_tmp.strip():
       key = key_tmp.split('\t')
       key = ' '.join(key)
       print '%s\t%s\t%s' %(key,1,count_result)
```

Comment: Bear in mind that also "qry_src=" and "src=" match `.*rc=`. I strongly doubt that there are bugs with `regex`.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely is that your regular expression catches more that you expect. I would suggest to split it to some more simple parts like:

```
(?<= qry=).*(?= quid0)
```

and

```
(?<= rc=).*(?= discount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a lot of assumptions and hazarding an educated guess, you might be able to parse your log like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

input = """NOTICE: 01-03 23:57:23: [a.cpp][b][222] show_ver=11 sid=ae1d esid=6WVj uid=D1 a=20 qry=cars qid0=293 loc_src=4 phn=0 mid=0 wvar=c op=0 qry_src=0 op_type=1 src=110|120|111 at=60942 rc=3|1|1 discount=20 indv_type=0 rep_query=
NOTICE: 01-03 23:57:23: [a.cpp][b][222] show_ver=11 sid=ae1d esid=6WVj uid=D1 a=20 qry=boats qid0=293 loc_src=4 phn=0 mid=0 wvar=c op=0 qry_src=0 op_type=1 src=110|120|111 at=60942 rc=3|5|2 discount=20 indv_type=0 rep_query=
NOTICE: 01-03 23:57:23: [a.cpp][b][222] show_ver=11 sid=ae1d esid=6WVj uid=D1 a=20 qry=cars qid0=293 loc_src=4 phn=0 mid=0 wvar=c op=0 qry_src=0 op_type=1 src=110|120|111 at=60942 rc=3|somestring|12 discount=20 indv_type=0 rep_query="""

d = defaultdict (lambda: 0)

for line in input.split ("\n"):
    tokens = line.split (" ")
    count = 0
    qry = None
    for token in tokens:
        pair = token.split ("=")
        if len (pair) != 2: continue
        key, value = pair
        if key == "qry":
            qry = value
        if key == "rc":
            values = value.split ("|")
            for value in values:
                try: count += int (value)
                except: pass
    if qry: d [qry] += count

print (d)
```

Assuming, that (a) key-value pairs are separated by spaces, and (b) there are no spaces inside neither keys nor values.

Comment: Glad to hear it and to be of help.